# Exception happens on one Glassfish3 instance, but not the other: "java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.slf4j.Marker"

Tags: java, glassfish

I have a legacy codebase, a Java app that runs on Glassfish3. It deploys & runs fine on two app servers that were already there when I arrived.
I'm trying to setup a local instance, using Docker. When I deploy the WAR in the Docker Glassfish, it deploys fine. When I try to open the login page, it throws an exception (from the JSP compilation):

"java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.slf4j.Marker"

There isn't much more information, except suggestions to enable debug & verbose flags during compilation.

Same WAR deploys & runs without this error on the existing app servers.

My guess is that there's a configuration difference that I'm not aware of. Another angle I'm looking at is the logger implementation provided by the application server. Either way - so far I haven't been able to figure out what's the difference between the instances, or even how to figure out the difference in configuration/deployment.

Java EE isn't my natural habitat, so any ideas on what I should be looking at would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference -- the solution was to search the codebase for log warn/error/info/debug/trace calls with more than 3 parameters, and changing them from ("...", "...", "...", "...") to ("...", new Object[]{"...", "...", "..."})